# Generating rails controller starts up the server afterwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time I try to generate a rails controller in windows it starts up the server after generating the necessary file.

```
$ rails g controller supprefresh index process                                                                
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated                                                         
C:/Rubies/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/shared/Win32API.rb:11 warning: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective 
      create  app/controllers/supprefresh_controller.rb                                                       
       route  get "supprefresh/process"                                                                       
       route  get "supprefresh/index"                                                                         
      invoke  erb                                                                                             
      create    app/views/supprefresh                                                                         
      create    app/views/supprefresh/index.html.erb                                                          
      create    app/views/supprefresh/process.html.erb                                                        
      invoke  rspec                                                                                           
      create    spec/controllers/supprefresh_controller_spec.rb                                               
      create    spec/views/supprefresh                                                                        
      create    spec/views/supprefresh/index.html.erb_spec.rb                                                 
      create    spec/views/supprefresh/process.html.erb_spec.rb                                               
      invoke  helper                                                                                          
      create    app/helpers/supprefresh_helper.rb                                                             
      invoke    rspec                                                                                         
      create      spec/helpers/supprefresh_helper_spec.rb                                                     
      invoke  assets                                                                                          
      invoke    coffee                                                                                        
      create      app/assets/javascripts/supprefresh.js.coffee                                                
      invoke    scss                                                                                          
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/supprefresh.css.scss                                                 
[2019-04-09 16:18:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1                                                                     
[2019-04-09 16:18:34] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-12-06) [java]                                                    
[2019-04-09 16:18:34] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind - Address already in use: bind     
== Someone is already performing on port 4567!
```

I'm running rails 4 with jruby 1.7 on windows

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Did you customise the rails generator template by any chance?

Comment: No I haven't done anything like that

Comment: Would it be possible to share your Gemfile?
Is this a new project? If not, could you try to replicate creating a new project?
`rails new test_generators`

Comment: I think, you should try with Creating new Project by   `rails new _project_name` and try with same command `rails g controller supprefresh index process` 
if it create same issue, than may be issue with your system.